# how to get frequency response of a numerical "black box" function

Tags: python, numpy, numeric

I have write a speed estimator that is in my opinion less that optimal, but it perform better that when corrected (the question is not relative to this error, thus I don't give more detail to stay on wanted answer only).

I would like to see frequency response of following code (called at regular interval, like each 100us), any one to guide me with python (and maybe numpy or scipy) on this ?

EDIT: according to mkrieger1 advice, I modified and completed my code

```
from scipy import signal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

class blackBox:
    tick = 0
    result = 0
    er1 = er2 = er3 = er4 = er5 = er6 = er7 =  0

    def __call__(s,input):
        s.tick+=1        
        if (s.tick==5):        
            s.tick = 0
            s.result = input + 5.0*s.er1 + 9.0*s.er2 + 5.0*s.er3 -5.0*s.er4 -9.0*s.er5 -5.0*s.er6 - s.er7
            s.er7 = s.er6;
            s.er6 = s.er5;
            s.er5 = s.er4;
            s.er4 = s.er3;
            s.er3 = s.er2;
            s.er2 = s.er1;
            s.er1 = input;

        return s.result        

p = blackBox()
imp = signal.unit_impulse(20000,4) # pulse need to be at really specific place 
out = np.empty(20000)
sample_rate = 20000
n = imp.size

for i,val in enumerate(imp):
    out[i] = p(val)

f = np.fft.rfft(out)
f1 = abs(f)
freq = np.fft.fftfreq(n, d=1./sample_rate)
plt.plot(freq[:10001],f1)
```

this show what frequency may be. Still a problem, I need to send the pulse specificaly when the black box take it.... this mean real frequency response will most probably be different. Is it possible to use kind of random noise to do exitation, and to perform someting like fft(out/in) ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "frequency response of code".

Comment: Are you asking how to calculate the discrete Fourier transform of a sequence of values?

Comment: assume you have this process called each 100us with some data input (exitation), we will have same number of data output (mesure), theses are discrete values on time domain. I would like to see the frequency response (measure/input) of this process in frequency domain.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Fourrier Transform will be needed. What I search is something similar to scipy.signal.freqz ( https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.freqz.html ) but for my special black box process.

Comment: So pass a unit impulse as input to your black box function, store sufficiently many output values in an array and calculate the DFT. See e.g. https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.fft.html